# Why does timedelta work differently when working with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have this function where it calculates today. I am wondering why is the following results are happening.

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
```

shows as 2018-06-13 17:13:42.372469

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

shows as 2018-06-13

but when I try to use timedelta like this:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(hours=-8)
```

it shows 2018-06-12. A full day back instead of 8 hours (should show 2018-06-13 9:13:42)

Can someone please explain why this happens and have timedelta correctly go back 8 hours instead of a day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reducing the timestamp to the date only, you have effectively set the time to 00:00:00 - substracting 8 hours from 2018-06-13 midnight correctly results in 2018-06-12.

Why not use the correct timestamps for calculation, and only convert them to dates after you have performed them?

Comment: Hi, this answered my question. Thank you very much!